# Angularjs Ng-view animations

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, ng-view

Using angularjs 1.4.3, I would like to apply transition animations to my views on enter and leave. I've been using the angularjs ng-view documentation to try to implement these animations. I have routed my pages correctly and all of them appear just fine but I can't seem to get these animations working. I don't understand some of the documentation so I may be completely off in how I executed this piece of code.

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="App">
    <main ng-controller="MainController" class="view-animate-container"> 
        <div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
    </main>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.view-animate-container {
  position:relative;
}

.view-animate {
  padding:10px;
}

.view-animate.ng-enter, .view-animate.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;

  display:block;
  width:100%;
  border-left:1px solid black;

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  padding:10px;
}

.view-animate.ng-enter {
  left:100%;
}
.view-animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  left:0;
}
.view-animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left:-100%;
}
```